# Selection Sort in c++

Tags: c++, sorting, selection

i'm trying to understand selection sort from this video:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=79AB11J5BqU

this is my current code :

```
#include <iostream>
int main() {
int numbers[5]={5,3,4,1,2};
int temp;

std::cout<<"BEFORE SORT : \n";
for(int x=0;x<5;x++){
    std::cout<<numbers[x]<<" ";
}

for (int i = 0; i < 5; ++i) {
    for (int j = i+1; j < 5; ++j) {
        if(numbers[j]<numbers[i]){
            temp = numbers[j];
            numbers[j] = numbers[i];
            numbers[i] = temp;
        }
    }
}

std::cout<<"\n\nAFTER SORT : \n";
for(int x=0;x<5;x++){
    std::cout<<numbers[x]<<" ";
}
}
```

Am i doing the selection sort just like the video?
or am i instead doing buble sort ?

Thanks

Comment: In selectionsort you are supposed to find the least element, then swap once.

Comment: so , did the explanation in video wrong ?

Comment: to the DOWNVOTER, may i know what do i do wrong that you think you need to downvotes ? :(

Comment: As state in one video comment, it is not [Selection_sort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Selection_sort).

Comment: @Jarod42 did using j+1 and move the smallest number to first index and so on  doesn't make it Selection_sort ?

Comment: this code also say it selection > http://www.cplusplus.com/forum/beginner/46753/

Comment: I would say it is a variation of selection sort, as I don't find a match on wikipedia.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In selection sort you find a minimal (or maximal) element and put it to top (bottom), then repeat it again for the rest of list.

It would be a selection sort, but you don't need to do swap every number you compare to find the smallest one. Store smallest number index in each internal loop and do one swap at the end of it.

```
 unsigned minIndex;
 for (int i = 0; i < 5; ++i) {
     minIndex = i;
    for (int j = i + 1; j < 5; ++j) {
        if(numbers[j] < numbers[minIndex]){
            minIndex = j;
        }
    }
    if (minIndex != i) {  //  Do swapping
        temp = numbers[i];
        numbers[i] = numbers[minIndex];
        numbers[minIndex] = temp;
    }
}
```

Comment: [Bubble_sort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bubble_sort) only swaps adjacent item.

Comment: did using j+1 and move the smallest number to first index and so on doesn't make it Selection_sort ?

if not , then how is the right way to use selection sort ?

Comment: http://www.cplusplus.com/forum/beginner/46753/ < this one also say that it is selection , i am confused

Comment: @taek I'd say it's not the most common or effective spinoff of selection sort.

Answer (score 1):

The selection sort algorithm sorts an array by repeatedly finding the minimum element (considering ascending order) from unsorted part and putting it at the beginning.

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
// Selection Sort//
void Selection_Sort(int a[],int n)
{
for(int i=0;i<n-1;i++)
{
    int min_index=i;
    for(int j=i;j<n-1;j++)
    {
        if(a[j]<a[min_index]){
            min_index=j;
    }
    }
    swap(a[i],a[min_index]);

}
}
int main()
{

    int n,key;
    cin>>n;
    int a[1000];
    for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
        cin>>a[i];
    }
    Selection_Sort(a,n);
     for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
        cout<<a[i];
    }
}
```

Comment: The condition on the second-level for loop should be `j < n`, not `j < n-1`